# Him or himself? Which to use?

Tags: sentence

> He took his younger sister with **himself**.

In the above sentence, what would come here **him** or **himself**?
Also I am pretty confused in usage of these reflexive pronouns. Can you remove this confusion in short yet wholesome manner?

Comment: It would be _**him**_.  But a more idiomatic sentence would be (assuming they went somewhere) _He went  with **his** younger sister._

Comment: @3kstc: except he's driving, so he took his younger sister with him.

Comment: No, she wants to go to the mall and her brother is going in that direction, so their mother threatens him with a long and painful death if he doesn't take his younger sister with him. If he took his younger sister driving, they're likely just looking at scenery.

Comment: 'He took his younger sister,' expresses the fact that he was there and she was there and he was the one who initiated the situation.

Comment: There is no need for a reflexive here, "him" is fine.

Answer (score 1):

'With himself' is wrong. 'With him' is accepted but not needed. It is enough to say,'He took his younger sister." Readers can figure out that means 'with him' easily enough.

Comment: I agree but, annoyingly, native speakers who should know better use the reflexive incorrectly all the time because they think it sounds more formal.